# Set multiple properties in a List<T> ForEach()?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a class:

```
class foo
{
    public string a = "";
    public int b = 0;
}
```

Then a generic list of them:

```
var list = new List<foo>(new []{new foo(), new foo()});
```

If I am to assign **multiple** properties inside the following `List<T>` `ForEach()` method, is there a simpler way to do it that below? Hopefully I'm being a bit thick.

```
// one property - easy peasy
list.ForEach(lambda => lambda.a="hello!");
// multiple properties - hmm
list.ForEach(lambda => new Action(delegate() { lambda.a = "hello!"; lambda.b = 99;}).Invoke());
```

Edit: Thought `ForEach()` was a LINQ extension method, when it's actually part of `List<T>` oops!

Comment: I don't have any clue for your answer, but I'm very interested for this methodology of this code. Could you please define what an Action is?

Comment: Not that it matters, but this is a method on `List<T>` and is not LINQ. Also, you could create your list with `var list = new List<foo>() { new foo(), new foo() };`

Comment: @Anwar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Answer (score 342, accepted):

All you need to do is introduce some brackets so that your anonymous method can support multiple lines:

```
list.ForEach(i => { i.a = "hello!"; i.b = 99; });
```

Answer (score 58):

Anonymous method is your friend

```
list.ForEach(item => 
              { 
                  item.a = "hello!"; 
                  item.b = 99; 
              });
```

MSDN:

- [Anonymous Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

```
list.ForEach(lamba=>lambda.a="hello!");
```

Becomes

```
list.ForEach(item=>{
     item.a = "hello!";
     item.b = 99;
});
```

Of course you can also assign them when you create the list like :

```
var list = new List<foo>(new []{new foo(){a="hello!",b=99}, new foo(){a="hello2",b=88}});
```

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, there's really no need to use List.ForEach here:

```
foreach (var item in list) { item.a="hello!"; item.b=99; }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list.ForEach(i => i.DoStuff());
public void DoStuff(this foo lambda)
{
  lambda.a="hello!"; 
  lambda.b=99;
}
```